# DataGridView Row Click to Linq Object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I'm a beginner with C# so I made a little app, to figure out how to work with Linq and databased in C#.

What I'm trying to do is in a `DataGridView` when someone clicks a row containing some data I want to go from `e.RowIndex` to a Linq object of the data in that row, my attempt involved using the `DataBoundItem`.

But for whatever reason the `currentAd` variable in this code always gives me a null value.

```
    private void clickRow(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "There is a clickRow event with row index " + e.RowIndex;
        Ad currentAd = adsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Ad;
        if (currentAd != null) // The problem is it is always null
        {
            MessageBox.Show( currentAd.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the examples given on the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx), they cast the row to a `DataGridViewRow` object first, before taking the `DataBoundItem`, so you might want to try it this way:

```
    private void clickRow(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "There is a clickRow event with row index " + e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = adsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewRow;
        Ad currentAd = row.DataBoundItem as Ad;
        if (currentAd != null) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show( currentAd.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I looked over there and I was trying to play around with that and it still wasn't working. I tried it and it was still giving null.

Comment: It would seem then that your cast to `Ad` is failing.